# How to format the name of the checkbox while send by a GET cakephp

Tags: cakephp, checkbox, get

I would like to know if it's possible to format the name of the checkbox when I try to send it to my other page via a GET method.

Actually I've got a multiple checkboxes that generate something like:

```
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1" id="ResearchTest1" /><label for="ResearchTest1">First Test</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2" id="ResearchTest2" /><label for="ResearchTest2">Second Test</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="3" id="ResearchTest3" /><label for="ResearchTest3">Third Test</label></div>
```

And when I send my form, my URL looks like:

```
research%3D%26test%3D%26test%5B%5D%3D1%26test%5B%5D%3D2%26test%5B%5D%3D3
```

Which is :

```
research=&test=&test[]=1&test[]=2&test[]=3
```

And what I would like, will be:

```
research=&test1=1&test2=2&test3=3
```

Or

```
research=&test=1&test=2&test=3
```

Or, much better:

```
 research=&test=1,2,3
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you generate those inputs with FormHelper? Show us your CakePHP code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using: $this->Form->input('tests', array('type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $options));

Answer (score 0):

You can define the name of the input using the FormHelper:

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('yourInputId', array('name' => 'yourInputName'));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how checkboxes work, if you want  `test1=1&test2=2&test3=3` then you should name each checkbox individually.

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('foo', array('name' => 'test1'));
echo $this->Form->checkbox('foo', array('name' => 'test2'));
echo $this->Form->checkbox('foo', array('name' => 'test3'));
```

This will make your processing much harder.

You can do `research=&test=1,2,3` with JS `join()`. Why you want to make this difficult for yourself I dont know. You can easily get that same format in the controller doint the GET with `implode(',', $theData)`

I would recommend using `standards` for submitting your form and process the data later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I use a multiple checkboxes:

```
$this->Form->input('tests', array('type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $options));
```

So I can't rename each checkbox individually.

Maybe I should not use cakephp for this, but try to write my own checkboxes directly in html?